How to determine large point for the same x axis in the elliptic curve cryptography?
For a given X value of elliptic curve cryptography there are two Y values. One point is P(x,y) and another point is Q(x1,y1) where P =-Q or Q = -P. Suppose given X value is 103388573995635080359749164254216598308788835304023601477803095234286494993683
Then output Y will be
37057141145242123013015316630864329550140216928701153669873286428255828810018
and
78734948092074072410555668377823578303129767736939410369584297579653005861645
So,
P = (103388573995635080359749164254216598308788835304023601477803095234286494993683, 37057141145242123013015316630864329550140216928701153669873286428255828810018) and
Q = (103388573995635080359749164254216598308788835304023601477803095234286494993683, 78734948092074072410555668377823578303129767736939410369584297579653005861645)
Also generator point G =(55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240,
32670510020758816978083085130507043184471273380659243275938904335757337482424) = 1
-G = (55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240,
-32670510020758816978083085130507043184471273380659243275938904335757337482424) = -1
or
-G = (55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240,
83121579216557378445487899878180864668798711284981320763518679672151497189239) = -1
If G is added to P and Q, what will correct answer between P+G > Q+G  or P+G < Q + G? How to identify it from the given x value?

How do you define the comparison between elliptic curve points?

G point = 1  ; After doubling 2G = 2, After point addition =3,4,5 .....

So, $xG > yG$ is $x > y$.  In a while, I'll show you why we hope that's not feasible

this is how private key to public key is generated for bitcoin

and that's why it's hopefully not feasible, otherwise it would be a break of bitcoin

yes, understood. Otherwise many people will loose their asset.


If G is added to P and Q, what will correct answer between P+G > Q+G or P+G < Q + G?

You're essentially asking "given two points $P$ and $-P$ (and thus, $xG$ and $-xG$), how do we determine which is the smaller?
The answer is: we hope that is infeasible.
Here's why: if we have a magic box that, given $P$ and $-P$, determines which is smaller (that is, which is the smaller multiple of $G$), then we can compute discrete logs (and thus break ECC on this curve).
Here's why: when we compute $P$ and $-P$, we are actually comparing $x$ and $n-x$ (where $xG = P$ and $n$ is the order of $G$).  If $x < n-x$, then we know that $x < n/2$; if $x > n-x$, then $x > n/2$.  That is, it acts as an Oracle to determine whether $P$ is in the 'first half' of the internal of multiples of $G$ or the second half.
So, to compute the discrete log of $P$, we call our Oracle to determine whether $x < n/2$ or $x > n/2$ - let us say that it's in the first half ($x < n/2$).  What we would do then is compute $2P$ and pass it to our Oracle, which would tell us if $2x < n$ or $2x > n$ - that is, if it's in the first quarter or the second (and we could do the same if it turned out that $x > n/2$).
Continuing on, we could repeat this, doing binary search, until we find the value of $x$, using $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil$ calls to our Oracle, thus solving the discrete log problem.

I have found a way of doing it. But finally failed.
